# GStreamer how define fraction property that will accept '4/3'

Tags: c, gstreamer, gobject

I am adding a property to a GStreamer element which is an euclidean fraction, so numerator and denominator.

It works fine so long as the numerator is smaller than the denominator but not otherwise.

So pixel-aspect-ratio=3/4 works, but pixel-aspect-ratio=4/3 returns the following error:

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 22:26:35.974: value "4/3" of type
'GstFraction' is invalid or out of range for property
'pixel-aspect-ratio' of type 'GstFraction'
```

Below my code to define the property.  I have tried various combinations for the min_num, min_denom, max_num and max_denom to no avail. There is not enough detail in the doc. I am hoping someone here can spot the obvious mistake so I do not have to sieve through the code for gst_value_compare () which appears to be the function that produces the error.

```
  g_object_class_install_property (gobject_class, PROP_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO,
      gst_param_spec_fraction ("pixel-aspect-ratio",
          "Pixel aspect ratio",
          "Pixel aspect ratio of frames in the stream",
          0, G_MAXINT, G_MAXINT, G_MAXINT,
          DEFAULT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO_NUM, DEFAULT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO_DEN,
          G_PARAM_READWRITE | G_PARAM_STATIC_STRINGS)
      );
```

I should add that my understanding of the fraction type is that it allows to express a euclidean division as num and den and avoids using floats.  Let me know if I misunderstand the concept. Either the doc is too sparse or I have not found the right info.

Comment: I'm not really faimilar with GStreamer but this lines seems odd to me: `0, G_MAXINT, G_MAXINT, G_MAXINT,` Which parameters do you want to provide here? If [this](https://www.manpagez.com/html/gstreamer-1.0/gstreamer-1.0-1.14.3/gstreamer-GstParamSpec.php) is the function you are using, then you have `min_denom` equal `G_MAXINT`.

Comment: You have told it the minimum fraction is 0/G_MAXINT (i.e. 0) and the maximum fraction is G_MAXINT/G_MAXINT (i.e. 1). But 4/3 > 1.

Comment: This is me having tried all possible combinations to try and figure out what these arguments are and copied the last, most unlikely iteration. What I originally wrote and I think should be correct is: 0, 1, G_MAXINT, G_MAXINT.

Comment: How about 0, 1, G_MAXINT, 1?

Comment: Yeap, setting max_denom to 1 works. But why? From the doc:  max_denom – maximum value (fraction denominator). It should not accept a value greater than 1, or what am I missing?